# Sqoop export to postgres with --schema argument

Tags: postgresql, export, sqoop

Is there any way to mention different schema when exporting data to postgresql using Sqoop?

Based on the URL http://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.4/SqoopUserGuide.html, I need to use `-- --schema` which is pretty weird, well it doesn't work.

I tried to use `--schema` as well, but still same result.
`-- --schema` works with list-tables command but not with `export` command.

Any helps will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

It finally worked. In order to use "-- --schema", we need to provide that option at the very end,  not in the middle. So this one will work:

```
--connect jdbc:postgresql://xxx/abcd --username xxx --password xxx --table xxx --input-fields-terminated-by '\001' --input-lines-terminated-by '\n' --num-mappers 8 --input-null-string '\\N' --input-null-non-string '\\N' --export-dir /user/hadoop/xxx -- --schema stage
```

Whereas this one will not work:

```
--connect jdbc:postgresql://xxx/abcd --username xxx --password xxx  -- --schema stage --table xxx --input-fields-terminated-by '\001' --input-lines-terminated-by '\n' --num-mappers 8 --input-null-string '\\N' --input-null-non-string '\\N' --export-dir /user/hadoop/xxx
```

By default you might be thinking to put schema name before mentioning table name, but that will not work. It would have been great if this information was included in the Sqoop document.

Answer (score 0):

Yes using the -- --schema  at the end of the sqoop export statement worked fine.

By default the the schema "dbo" is picked up in sqoop export.

Answer (score 0):

> The `--schema` parameter must be separated from the rest of the parameters with an extra set of dashes (i.e. `--` ) and the `--schema` parameter must come last.

Refer: [Sqoop Export Cookbook](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/SQOOP/Export+Cookbook)